# Missing References in Excel-VBA workbook

Tags: c#, vba, excel, visual-studio-setup-proje

I've got an Excel-VBA spreadsheet that is installed with a Visual Studios Setup Project...

I made a changes to the VBA code, tested the change, plugged the new spreadsheet into the setup project, built the setup project and sent it to Q/A.

I got a response back saying that she couldn't even get the thing installed... One of the projects (Called BMath) is missing a reference in the VBA spreadsheet...

It appears to me that the path is being split after the '#':

**Missing BMath Path:**

> C:\_Data\B\1.0\20161007_1024\C

**Working BPattern Path:**

> C:\_Data\B\1.0\20161007_1024\C#\B\Deployment\BPattern.tlb

Why would this ONLY be happening to BMath, and not the other (7) references in that exact same folder? (C:\_Data\B\1.0\20161007_1024\C#\B\Deployment\)

Thanks for the input.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202261